# atomic orbitals calculation in Heisenberg picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, orbitals

It sounds like this question was answered at the beginning of the last century. Nevertheless, going through some notes on basic quantum mechanics I noticed that Schordinger picture enables one to visualise atomic orbitals and explain directionality of chemical bondings.

Is it possible to calculate (probability) of an atomic orbital distribution in space in Heisenberg picture ?
If not, how can the two pictures be equivalent ?

Thanks !

Comment: By saying "an atomic orbital distribution", do you mean electrons/charge distribution? If you read the formalism here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture, the charge distribution can be calculated if you insert the density operator in the place of $A(t)$.

Comment: I mean spatial distribution. Can you elaborate a bit more how to get something like this in HP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#/media/File:Hydrogen_Density_Plots.png